# Extracting data from JSON File to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have a big JSON file with a very complex structure

you can look on it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tBVJ2xYSCpTTUGPJegvAz2ZXbeN0bteX/view?usp=sharing

it contains more than 7 millions lines, and I want to extract only the "text" field

I have written a python code, to extra all the values of the "text" key or field in the whole file, and it extracted only 12 values! while when I open the JSON file on the Visualstudio, I have more than 19000 values!!

you can see the code here:

```
import json
import csv
with open("/Users/zahraa-maher/rasa-init-demo/venv/Tickie/external_data/frames2.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

fname = "outputText8.csv"

with open(fname, "w") as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file,lineterminator='\n')
    csv_file.writerow(["text"])
    for item in data[i]["turns"]:
        csv_file.writerow([item['text']])
```

please take a look on the JSON file as it is very large one and with a complex structure, so I an not paste it here to see because it would be not understandable

also this is a part of the son file:

```
[
    {
        "user_id": "U22HTHYNP",
        "turns": [
            {
                "text": "I'd like to book a trip to Atlantis from Caprica on Saturday, August 13, 2016 for 8 adults. I have a tight budget of 1700.",
                "labels": {
                    "acts": [
                        {
                            "args": [
                                {
                                    "val": "book",
                                    "key": "intent"
                                }
                            ],
                            "name": "inform"
                        },
                        {
                            "args": [
                                {
                                    "val": "Atlantis",
                                    "key": "dst_city"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Caprica",
                                    "key": "or_city"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Saturday, August 13, 2016",
                                    "key": "str_date"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "8",
                                    "key": "n_adults"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "1700",
                                    "key": "budget"
                                }
                            ],
                            "name": "inform"
                        }
                    ],
                    "acts_without_refs": [
                        {
                            "args": [
                                {
                                    "val": "book",
                                    "key": "intent"
                                }
                            ],
                            "name": "inform"
                        },
                        {
                            "args": [
                                {
                                    "val": "Atlantis",
                                    "key": "dst_city"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Caprica",
                                    "key": "or_city"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Saturday, August 13, 2016",
                                    "key": "str_date"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "8",
                                    "key": "n_adults"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "1700",
                                    "key": "budget"
                                }
                            ],
                            "name": "inform"
                        }
                    ],
                    "active_frame": 1,
                    "frames": [
                        {
                            "info": {
                                "intent": [
                                    {
                                        "val": "book",
                                        "negated": false
                                    }
                                ],
                                "budget": [
                                    {
                                        "val": "1700.0",
                                        "negated": false
                                    }
                                ],
                                "dst_city": [
                                    {
                                        "val": "Atlantis",
                                        "negated": false
                                    }
                                ],
                                "or_city": [
                                    {
                                        "val": "Caprica",
                                        "negated": false
                                    }
                                ],
                                "str_date": [
                                    {
                                        "val": "august 13",
                                        "negated": false
                                    }
                                ],
                                "n_adults": [
                                    {
                                        "val": "8",
                                        "negated": false
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "frame_id": 1,
                            "requests": [],
                            "frame_parent_id": null,
                            "binary_questions": [],
                            "compare_requests": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "author": "user",
                "timestamp": 1471272019730.0
            },
            {
                "db": {
                    "result": [
                        [
                            {
                                "trip": {
                                    "returning": {
                                        "duration": {
                                            "hours": 0,
                                            "min": 51
                                        },
                                        "arrival": {
                                            "hour": 10,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 24,
                                            "min": 51,
                                            "month": 8
                                        },
                                        "departure": {
                                            "hour": 10,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 24,
                                            "min": 0,
                                            "month": 8
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "seat": "ECONOMY",
                                    "leaving": {
                                        "duration": {
                                            "hours": 0,
                                            "min": 51
                                        },
                                        "arrival": {
                                            "hour": 0,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 16,
                                            "min": 51,
                                            "month": 8
                                        },
                                        "departure": {
                                            "hour": 0,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 16,
                                            "min": 0,
                                            "month": 8
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "or_city": "Porto Alegre",
                                    "duration_days": 9
                                },
                                "price": 2118.81,
                                "hotel": {
                                    "gst_rating": 7.15,
                                    "vicinity": [],
                                    "name": "Scarlet Palms Resort",
                                    "country": "Brazil",
                                    "amenities": [
                                        "FREE_BREAKFAST",
                                        "FREE_PARKING",
                                        "FREE_WIFI"
                                    ],
                                    "dst_city": "Goiania",
                                    "category": "3.5 star hotel"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "trip": {
                                    "returning": {
                                        "duration": {
                                            "hours": 2,
                                            "min": 37
                                        },
                                        "arrival": {
                                            "hour": 12,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 10,
                                            "min": 37,
                                            "month": 8
                                        },
                                        "departure": {
                                            "hour": 10,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 10,
                                            "min": 0,
                                            "month": 8
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "seat": "ECONOMY",
                                    "leaving": {
                                        "duration": {
                                            "hours": 2,
                                            "min": 37
                                        },
                                        "arrival": {
                                            "hour": 0,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 4,
                                            "min": 37,
                                            "month": 8
                                        },
                                        "departure": {
                                            "hour": 22,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 3,
                                            "min": 0,
                                            "month": 8
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "or_city": "Porto Alegre",
                                    "duration_days": 7
                                },
                                "price": 2369.83,
                                "hotel": {
                                    "gst_rating": 0,
                                    "vicinity": [],
                                    "name": "Sunway Hostel",
                                    "country": "Argentina",
                                    "amenities": [
                                        "FREE_BREAKFAST",
                                        "FREE_WIFI"
                                    ],
                                    "dst_city": "Rosario",
                                    "category": "2.0 star hotel"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "trip": {
                                    "returning": {
                                        "duration": {
                                            "hours": 0,
                                            "min": 51
                                        },
                                        "arrival": {
                                            "hour": 10,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 24,
                                            "min": 51,
                                            "month": 8
                                        },
                                        "departure": {
                                            "hour": 10,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 24,
                                            "min": 0,
                                            "month": 8
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "seat": "BUSINESS",
                                    "leaving": {
                                        "duration": {
                                            "hours": 0,
                                            "min": 51
                                        },
                                        "arrival": {
                                            "hour": 0,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 16,
                                            "min": 51,
                                            "month": 8
                                        },
                                        "departure": {
                                            "hour": 0,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 16,
                                            "min": 0,
                                            "month": 8
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "or_city": "Porto Alegre",
                                    "duration_days": 9
                                },
                                "price": 2375.72,
                                "hotel": {
                                    "gst_rating": 7.15,
                                    "vicinity": [],
                                    "name": "Scarlet Palms Resort",
                                    "country": "Brazil",
                                    "amenities": [
                                        "FREE_BREAKFAST",
                                        "FREE_PARKING",
                                        "FREE_WIFI"
                                    ],
                                    "dst_city": "Goiania",
                                    "category": "3.5 star hotel"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "trip": {
                                    "returning": {
                                        "duration": {
                                            "hours": 1,
                                            "min": 30
                                        },
                                        "arrival": {
                                            "hour": 11,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 1,
                                            "min": 30,
                                            "month": 9
                                        },
                                        "departure": {
                                            "hour": 10,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 1,
                                            "min": 0,
                                            "month": 9
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "seat": "BUSINESS",
                                    "leaving": {
                                        "duration": {
                                            "hours": 1,
                                            "min": 30
                                        },
                                        "arrival": {
                                            "hour": 18,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 19,
                                            "min": 30,
                                            "month": 8
                                        },
                                        "departure": {
                                            "hour": 17,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 19,
                                            "min": 0,
                                            "month": 8
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "or_city": "Porto Alegre",
                                    "duration_days": 13
                                },
                                "price": 2492.95,
                                "hotel": {
                                    "gst_rating": 0,
                                    "vicinity": [],
                                    "name": "Hotel Mundo",
                                    "country": "Brazil",
                                    "amenities": [
                                        "FREE_BREAKFAST",
                                        "FREE_WIFI",
                                        "FREE_PARKING"
                                    ],
                                    "dst_city": "Manaus",
                                    "category": "2.5 star hotel"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "trip": {
                                    "returning": {
                                        "duration": {
                                            "hours": 0,
                                            "min": 51
                                        },
                                        "arrival": {
                                            "hour": 10,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 31,
                                            "min": 51,
                                            "month": 8
                                        },
                                        "departure": {
                                            "hour": 10,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 31,
                                            "min": 0,
                                            "month": 8
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "seat": "ECONOMY",
                                    "leaving": {
                                        "duration": {
                                            "hours": 0,
                                            "min": 51
                                        },
                                        "arrival": {
                                            "hour": 19,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 27,
                                            "min": 51,
                                            "month": 8
                                        },
                                        "departure": {
                                            "hour": 19,
                                            "year": 2016,
                                            "day": 27,
                                            "min": 0,
                                            "month": 8
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "or_city": "Porto Alegre",
                                    "duration_days": 4
                                },
                                "price": 2538.0,
                                "hotel": {
                                    "gst_rating": 8.22,
                                    "vicinity": [],
                                    "name": "The Glee",
                                    "country": "Brazil",
                                    "amenities": [
                                        "FREE_BREAKFAST",
                                        "FREE_WIFI"
                                    ],
                                    "dst_city": "Recife",
                                    "category": "4.0 star hotel"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        [],
                        [],
                        [],
                        [],
                        [],
                        []
                    ],
                    "search": [
                        {
                            "ORIGIN_CITY": "Porto Alegre",
                            "PRICE_MIN": "2000",
                            "NUM_ADULTS": "2",
                            "timestamp": 1471271949.995,
                            "PRICE_MAX": "3000",
                            "ARE_DATES_FLEXIBLE": "true",
                            "NUM_CHILDREN": "5",
                            "START_TIME": "1470110400000",
                            "MAX_DURATION": 2592000000.0,
                            "DESTINATION_CITY": "Brazil",
                            "RESULT_LIMIT": "10",
                            "END_TIME": "1472616000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "ORIGIN_CITY": "Atlantis",
                            "NUM_ADULTS": "8",
                            "RESULT_LIMIT": "10",
                            "timestamp": 1471272148.124,
                            "PRICE_MAX": "1700",
                            "NUM_CHILDREN": "",
                            "ARE_DATES_FLEXIBLE": "true",
                            "START_TIME": "NaN",
                            "END_TIME": "NaN"
                        },
                        {
                            "ORIGIN_CITY": "Caprica",
                            "PRICE_MAX": "1700",
                            "NUM_ADULTS": "8",
                            "RESULT_LIMIT": "10",
                            "timestamp": 1471272189.07,
                            "DESTINATION_CITY": "Atlantis",
                            "NUM_CHILDREN": "",
                            "ARE_DATES_FLEXIBLE": "true",
                            "START_TIME": "1470715200000",
                            "END_TIME": "1472011200000"
                        },
                        {
                            "ORIGIN_CITY": "Caprica",
                            "PRICE_MAX": "1700",
                            "NUM_ADULTS": "8",
                            "RESULT_LIMIT": "10",
                            "timestamp": 1471272205.436,
                            "DESTINATION_CITY": "Atlantis",
                            "NUM_CHILDREN": "",
                            "ARE_DATES_FLEXIBLE": "true",
                            "START_TIME": "1470715200000",
                            "END_TIME": "1472011200000"
                        },
                        {
                            "ORIGIN_CITY": "Caprica",
                            "PRICE_MIN": "1700",
                            "NUM_ADULTS": "8",
                            "RESULT_LIMIT": "10",
                            "timestamp": 1471272278.72,
                            "DESTINATION_CITY": "Atlantis",
                            "NUM_CHILDREN": "",
                            "ARE_DATES_FLEXIBLE": "true",
                            "START_TIME": "1470715200000",
                            "END_TIME": "1472011200000"
                        },
                        {
                            "ORIGIN_CITY": "Caprica",
                            "PRICE_MIN": "1700",
                            "NUM_ADULTS": "8",
                            "RESULT_LIMIT": "10",
                            "timestamp": 1471272454.542,
                            "DESTINATION_CITY": "Atlantis",
                            "NUM_CHILDREN": "",
                            "ARE_DATES_FLEXIBLE": "true",
                            "START_TIME": "1471060800000",
                            "END_TIME": "1472011200000"
                        },
                        {
                            "ORIGIN_CITY": "Caprica",
                            "PRICE_MIN": "1700",
                            "NUM_ADULTS": "8",
                            "RESULT_LIMIT": "10",
                            "timestamp": 1471272466.008,
                            "DESTINATION_CITY": "Atlantis",
                            "NUM_CHILDREN": "",
                            "ARE_DATES_FLEXIBLE": "true",
                            "START_TIME": "1471060800000",
                            "END_TIME": "1472011200000"
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

How it could be modified to extract all the "text" values from the JSON file to a CSV file?

Comment: Where is i defined and increased , I dont see it in your code

Comment: Actually, I have not defined it, I put it because when I write for item in data[item]["turns"] it shows an errors.  I am beginner in python and just want to do the extraction with it.  can you guide me how can I modefy it to work well and extract all the needed data?

Comment: If Data is Json type , you should iterate in differently , for keys,values in  data.items()

Comment: could you write it in a code in answer and show me how to do that? as I told you I am a beginner and cannot understand that

Comment: First off, what is i in `data[i]['turns]`?  Secondly, the json is more complex than what this code can handle.  For example, the second instance of 'text' is data[0]['turns'][1]['db'].  You will need a generic way to traverse this monstrosity and find all the 'text' attributes.

Comment: `data[i]['turns]` those in a CSV file:
text
I need to book a trip for the whole family from Tampa but we don't know where to go. Can you help us?
Sure! How many are you and what's your budget?
5 adults and 7 kids! Yup, the lot of us. We want to spend no more than 32800.
Do you have any date constraints?

and some few more values as rows (only 12 rows)
but this is not the whole data, there lots and more rows must be extracted as the JSON file contains more than 19000 "text" values, and could you help me to find a generic method to do that?

Comment: I wrote the code as an answer

Comment: Please post sample of json in body of post and not as a large 7-million+  line file in an external link that may be blocked by corporate proxies or will go dead for future readers. We just need enough repetition to understand the pattern.

Comment: Ok, but the file need to be here as the sample may not be that enugh

Comment: Firstly, your question is off-topic. You're required to provide a [mcve] including input data (stripped down to the minimum as well). Secondly, consider using `jq` instead, which is a JSON processor and suitable for extracting information from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a potential solution using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
#importing data
dj = pd.read_json("frames2.json")
dtext = dj[["user_id","turns"]]
#Saving text records in a list
list_ = []
for record in dtext["turns"].values:
  for r  in record:
    list_.append(r["text"])
#Exporting the csv
out = pd.Series(list_,name="text")
out.to_csv("text.csv")
```

It gives the following output.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much:
it shows this error for me:
NameError: name 'dtext' is not defined

how may I resolve it?

Comment: Sorry I forgot a line in the code. Check my answer again I've edited it.

Comment: Thank you again, it also shows this error: 
NameError: name 'list_' is not defined

so you know how to resolve it?

Comment: It works! thank you very much for your assistance, I really appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import json
import csv
with open("/Users/zahraa-maher/rasa-init-demo/venv/Tickie/external_data/frames2.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

fname = "outputText8.csv"

with open(fname, "w") as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file,lineterminator='\n')
    csv_file.writerow(["text"])
    for keys,values in data.items():
```

now it up to you which of the fields you want to save, if you user a debugger you can see the values and Keys

Comment: Thank you very much, the code that I have added to after the for loop is that:
`csv_file.writerow([item['text']])` and it returns this error: 
<ipython-input-87-9d356da6b593> in <module>
      9     csv_file = csv.writer(file,lineterminator='\n')
     10     csv_file.writerow(["text"])
---> 11     for keys,values in data.items():
     12         csv_file.writerow([item['text']])

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Let say data={'text':'hi'} so keys will be equal to text and values will be equal to hi